# The offset position is wrong when setting a new element with the same offset of the clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So what i'm attempting to do is a tooltip/popover. Now i'm trying to ensure that whether you use a button format or just an anchor text that the tooltip is positioned based on the position of the button/anchor so that essentially whatever the element used with output the correct position.

**[FIDDLE GOES HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/egycjo7b/1/)**

As you will notice, if you click on the button or link, there will be two alerts:

```
// $el is essentially $(this) for the clicked element
var linkPosition = $el.offset();
alert(linkPosition.top);
```

Then I alert:

```
// $popover is the created popover based on the position of the $el (this instance)
var popoverPosition = $popover.offset();
alert(popoverPosition.top);
```

What you will notice, on the first alert instance the browser returns `8` and on the second instance `28` which confuses me greatly as I was expecting both values to be the same as the offset of the popover was set to be the offset of the button as you can see here:

```
$popover.css({
     top: linkPosition.top,
)};
```

Can anyone help me understand why the values are therefore different? As [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) states for offset that

> jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden
>   elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the
>   body element.

However for what i've done I feel that this should therefore output the correct values.

Any ideas? Thank you.

**PLEASE NOTE**: It looks like i've used twitter bootstrap, however I haven't I have simply used a similar approach of styles for this demonstration, thank you.

Comment: try to float Link to right and click again and let me know what you got?

Comment: what does floating the link to the right have to do with anything...? btw it does nothing other than the same thing in a different place lol.

Comment: I tried to explain if you float it right it will read the same offset().top of you button .. The .offset() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element (relative to the document).

Comment: Yes, however I need the offset of the button and the popover/tooltip to be the same...

Answer (score 0):

You get different value because that `Javascript` does not wait untill your `element` is transit to its new position, So, it take old value and `alert` them.

try to put some `timeout` to get `offset` and then `alert` them.

I put some `timeout` in your code see :

http://jsfiddle.net/egycjo7b/4/